# Form shows mistakenly the success alert box when it has invalid input in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the script below I check if the email entered is valid. It is not the best regex but it is ok for now. Also for the moment I do not make any server side check for input. Only with this script.

I have this problem though:
When an email is valid, and after I type an invalid email I get first the *Your email is not in valid format* and then *You will be notified when we launch. Thank you!* alert. Also the email is sent. How to fix this ?

Thank you

this is my form

```
<form id="myform" action="" method="POST">
                <input id="subscribe" name="subscribe" class="subscribe floatLeft" type="text">
                <button id="signUp" class="signUp floatRight" ><intro>notify!</intro></button>              
                <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
</form>
```

and here is the script

```
var signUp = function(inputEmail) {
    var isValid = true;
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    if (!emailReg.test(inputEmail)) {
        isValid = false;
        alert('Your email is not in valid format');
    }



$("#myform").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!isValid) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $.post('mailme.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
            alert('You will be notified when we launch. Thank you!');

        });
        return false;
    }
});

};
```

Comment: this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539752/how-to-refresh-only-a-part-of-the-page-when-f5-or-refresh-button-is-pressed/7539830#7539830

Comment: @asotshia Show your HTML, from where you're calling `signUp`.

Comment: You use the method Darhazer proposed and/or you use my answer inside your $(document).ready().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the onsubmit event to return false; 
You need to bind the submit event anyway and make the isValid check there;

```
$("#myform").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  if(!isValid){
  return false;
 }else{
  $.post(...)
  return false;
 }
});
```

--Edit--
Forgot to return false/event.preventDefault; But like i said, the submit event need to be bound anyway

--Edit2--

```
function validEmail(email){
var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
return email.test(emailReg)
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myform").bind({
    submit: function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     if(validEmail($("#myform").find("#subscribe").val()){
       $.post(...)
          alert("You will be notified");
         return false;
     }
     else {
        alert("Invalid email");
        return false;
     }

   });
```

});
}

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I managed to prevent reloading. However I updated my question, I would be very appreciated if you look at it.

Comment: the way you updated it should work, but it is a bit of a hassle...,are you putting onsubmit = "signUp(this.elements[0])" or as action or something similar? if you only bind the submit event on document.ready and make the check there it would be enough i guess. I'll put a code suggestion in my answer

Comment: Still not sure where you are calling this. The place where you need to get the email value, you need this on the submit event too. I mean you need the value of the input when the user presses the <button>, on submit.

Comment: :) do some console.log/alert if you work with. check the email value that is being validated with the function. also edited and changed #myInput with #subscribe to match your html

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return false` or `event.preventDefault()` in the `emailReg` test.

Comment: I tried `return false;` just after the `your email is not...` with no result

Comment: You need the onsubmit event to return false